# How to add specific terms in a custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, php, functions, custom-post-type-archives, e-commerce

I am creating a dedicated WordPress ecommerce website without using WooCommerce for myself. I created the custom post type called 'products' but now I am stuck on how to add specific terms like SKU, price, variations, short description, and related products section in it.

Can you please help me know. I don't know if I can specifically make sections to update such terms in the product post type.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should save this data in post_meta.
These values are part of every single product post and are different in every product.
You can add custom input fields with `add_meta_box()` function in the hook `add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'my_custom_metaboxes');` for example.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way?

Just use [Custom Post Type UI](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/) to create custom taxonomies (in your case: SKU, price, variations, short description, and related products).

And for the admin page, use [ACF](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) to add meta boxes to your products edit screen.

That's what I did. Then you can concentrate to other matters.